# org-preview-latex-fragment in higher resolution

Tags: org-mode, org-export, images

On a high res display, these latex fragments created by `C-c C-x C-l` are noticeably blurry compared to the text. I gather that they are processed with imagemagick--how can I tweak it to output higher res images?

Answer (score 4):

The variable `org-format-latex-options` (use `M-x customize-variable org-format-latex-options RET` to customize) is a property list with parameters controlling creation of images for LaTeX fragments. In particular, the `:scale` property controls image resolution. The default is `1.0`; set to `2.0` to double image resolution, etc.

To find an option like this one, try `M-x customize-group RET Org RET` and look for variables and subgroups that match what you want to adjust. In this case, `org-format-latex-options` is in the group `Org LaTeX`.

PS: Let me know if this works for you: my current machine does not have `dvipng` and so I cannot test this solution myself.

Comment: The `:scale` property does scale up the image, but it increases the size as well as the number of pixels. I can't find an option to adjust the density of pixels, for a crisper image. I would like to generate a larger image by increasing `:scale`, and then tell emacs to display that image in a smaller size--would this be possible?

Comment: Did you ever have any luck with this @sooheon?

Comment: No, there just wasn't the customization I wanted. I found that the emacs-mac [port](https://github.com/railwaycat/homebrew-emacsmacport) supports latex snippets in svgs driven by OSX, so I'm using that.